How to Read/Interpret Polars Lazy Frame Explanation and Show Graph?
Context
Using Polars data processing library via python on Linux
Relevant Class and Methods
polars.LazyFrame.show_graph and polars.LazyFrame.explain.
Question
The outputs of the above methods, when seen in a Jupyter notebook for simple cases, appear vaguely intuitive. But I am losing track of the different steps of processing for more complex Lazyframes formed from other lazy frames. Polars documentation does not have much information on how exactly to interpret those outputs (string, or image) either.
In particular, the output of explain looks vaguely like a SQL query, but I am losing it at its unique syntax at some places. To complicate, the explain has two modes, plantext and tree each having a different appearance.
So what are some formal ways to interpret the output of those methods and what kind of information can I get about a LazyFrame from those methods?
